# Append U+20000 or above UnicodeScalar to String

Tags: swift, unicode

Why can't I append `U+20000` or above `UnicodeScalar` to `String`?

```
var str = ""
let bmpScalar = UnicodeScalar(0x04e19) // 丙
let smpScalar = UnicodeScalar(0x1F600) // 
let sipScalar = UnicodeScalar(0x20011) // 

str.append(bmpScalar) // "丙"
str.append(smpScalar) // "丙"
str.append(sipScalar) // < [!] Exection was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
```

It compiles, but causes runtime error: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`.

While all of the following works:

```
str.extend(String(sipScalar))
str += String(sipScalar)
str.append(Character(sipScalar))
sipScalar.writeTo(&str)
```

Comment: If I interpret the assembler code correctly, appending a UnicodeScalar is only implemented for 0000xxxx and 0001xxxx values, all other cases jump to an UD2 instruction.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. Should I file a bug?

Comment: That's up to you. But you have an easily reproducible problem which looks like a bug, so why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Version 6.3 (6D520o)